# Editor Template not selecting value correct value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, kendo-ui, mvc-editor-templates

I have a Kendo grid with a custom edit button for each row. When a user clicks the edit button, a modal window opens where the user can edit the information and save the changes.

I've added an Editor Template to display a dropdownlist of state abbreviations.

StatesEditor.cshtml

```
@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
.Name("State") 
.DataValueField("StateID") 
.DataTextField("ShortName") 
.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["states"]))
```

This gets populated in my controller before I open my modal window:

```
public ActionResult OpenEditor([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, int? addressId)
    {
        var address = db.Address.Where(x => x.AddressId == addressId).FirstOrDefault();
        // code where I convert the address to an AddressMetadata
        // ...
        // ...

        ViewData["states"] = ACore.Methods.ViewDataPopulation.PopuldateStates();


        return PartialView("~/Views/System/Addresses/AddressEditorPopup.cshtml", addr);
    }
```

In my view I have

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.State)
```

and this is my model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ACore.Models
{
    [MetadataType(typeof(AddressMetadata))]
    public partial class Address
    {
    }

    public class AddressMetadata
    {   
        public int AddressID { get; set; }

        public string Street1 { get; set; }
        public string Street2 { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        [UIHint("StatesEditor")]
        public State State { get; set; }

        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and this is my States model:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace ACore.Models
{
    public class State
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The dropdownlist is being populated with a list of the states but it is set to "AK", the first state in the list. I'm passing my view a model where the state is to a State Model with an Id of 41 and a ShortName of "SC".

How can I get my dropdownlist to be set to the state I'm passing in?

UPDATED:

I don't know if this is the correct way to do this but this is how I fixed it. Just adding the SelectedIndex fixed the issue but I added the code above the DropDownList so I could use this editor in other places where I wasn't passing in the Id.

```
@model ACore.Models.State
@{
    var modelId = 0;
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    modelId = Model.Id - 1;
}


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("State")
    .DataValueField("StateID")
    .DataTextField("ShortName")
    .SelectedIndex(modelId)
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["states"])
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've answered my question in my updated comments above. I would still like to know if this is the recommended way to do this.

```
@model ACore.Models.State
@{
    var modelId = 0;
}
@if (Model != null)
{
    modelId = Model.Id - 1;
}


@(Html.Kendo().DropDownList()
    .Name("State")
    .DataValueField("StateID")
    .DataTextField("ShortName")
    .SelectedIndex(modelId)
    .BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["states"])
)
```